# If all powers of two random variables are uncorrelated, are they independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, moment-problem

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables on a common probability space. If $$\def\E{\mathbb E}\E[X^nY^m]=\E[X^n]\,\E[Y^m]<\infty $$ for all integers $n,m\ge 0$, does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I strongly suspect the answer is no. In the same way that the a random variable is not determined by its moments, a random vector is not determined by its joint moments. I have looked at several counter-examples of distinct random variables with the same moments, which I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790858/two-random-variables-with-same-moments). The examples are derived by looking at characteristic functions, but I am not sure if they can be generalized to multivariate characteristic functions.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884580/two-random-variables-are-independent-if-all-continuous-and-bounded-transformatio) shows that $\E[f(X)g(Y)]=\E[f(X)]\,\E[g(Y)]$ for all bounded and continuous $f$ and $g$ implies $X$ and $Y$ are independent. My question is if we get the same result when we restrict $f$ and $g$ to be polynomials.

Comment: Both links go to the same question. I think the latter is supposed to be to a different one, no?

Comment: @SamT Whoops, fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The answer is "it depends". See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325367/statement-about-independence-of-random-variables), and the references therein, in particular [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463082/does-independence-of-moments-imply-independence). The latter reference claims that it is true under certain assumptions on the size of the moments.

---

**[Linked answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325367/statement-about-independence-of-random-variables)** by Iosif Pinelis, copied verbatim to make this post self-contained (not my own work!)

The answer is no. Indeed, let $X:=\xi$ and $Y:=\eta$. Let $U$ and $V$ be any independent random variables (r.v.'s) with different distributions but with the same finite moments of all orders: 
$$EU^m=EV^m=:\mu_m$$
for all natural $m$. A standard example of the distributions of such r.v.'s $U$ and $V$ is given in [the answer by saz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166637/do-moments-define-distributions).

Let the cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F_{X,Y}$ of the random pair $(X,Y)$ be the half-and-half mixture of the cdf's $F_{U,V}$ and $F_{V,U}$, so that 
\begin{equation*}
 F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{F(x)G(y)+G(x)F(y)}2 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for all real $x,y$, where $F$ and $G$ are the cdf's of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then for the cdf's $F_X$ and $F_Y$ one has $F_X=F_Y=\frac{F+G}2$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
4[F_X(x)F_Y(y)-F_{X,Y}(x,y)]=[F(x)-G(x)][F(y)-G(y)]\ne0
\end{equation*}
for some real $x,y$, so that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

However, 
\begin{equation*}
 EX^mY^n=\tfrac12\,EU^m\, EV^n+\tfrac12\,EV^m\,EU^n=\mu_m\mu_n=EX^m\,EY^n \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for all natural $m,n$.

---

**Old answer**, left as I feel it gives at least a non-zero amount of insight

I'm not sure whether this should be posted as an answer or a comment, as it's certainly not complete. That said, I went for "answer", as people should be able to comment explicitly on it, agreeing, disagreeing or just commenting in general.

I think if one restricts to random variables with compact support, then it *may* be true. (I don't have a complete proof! -- otherwise, I'd remove the "may".) By Stone-Weierstrass, one can well-approximate any continuous, bounded function on a compact interval by a sequence of polynomials. By inspection of the proof in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884580/two-random-variables-are-independent-if-all-continuous-and-bounded-transformatio), it seems that one may well be able to apply a two-limit argument. The issue, though, is that one wouldn't have monotone convergence.

In particular, one has to approximate $1(\cdot \in I)$, for a bounded, open interval $I$. If the support of your random variable is $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ and is compact (or rather a subset of a compact set), then one can extend $S$ 'by $1$' to get $S'$ -- if $S = [a,b]$, then look at $S' = [a-1, b+1]$ -- and approximate $1(\cdot \in I)$ on $S'$. This may help apply the limits, as the approximating polynomials may well be better behaved.

Hopefully this answer is at least vaguely interesting!

Comment: Ah, I see I did not search MSE hard enough, and should have thought to search MO. Thanks! The answer in my case is "no," not "it depends," since i did not give any conditions on $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I didn't even search MO really, just went on there and looked at pr.probability to see if there was anything I could ask, and that question was asked earlier today! Quietly proud that my suggestion that it was true for bounded random variables turned out to be true!

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you edit in the content of the MO link, so the answer is self contained. Though I suppose this should be closed as a dupe anyway.

Comment: Self-contained now :)